# Implicit differentiation gives different results

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I want to find an expression for the derivative of the implicit function below:

$$\arctan(xy)=\frac{\pi}{4}e^{x-y}, \qquad \text{at point } (1,1)$$

I've tried to derive this using both Maple and Wolfram Alpha, and it appears that both of them give different results. So, I tried two different techniques (by hand):

1) Technique 1 (same result with Wolfram Alpha): differentiating both sides:$$\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(xy)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\pi}{4}e^{x-y}\\
\frac{y+xy'}{1+x^2y^2} = \frac{\pi}{4}(1-y')e^{x-y}\\
\frac{1+y'}{2} = \frac{\pi}{4}(1-y')e^{0}\\
2(1+y')=\pi(1-y')\\
2+2y'=\pi-\pi y'\\
y'=\frac{\pi-2}{\pi+2}
$$

2) Technique 2 (same result with Maple): expressing as $f(x,y)=C, \quad C \text{ is a constant}$

$$\frac{\arctan(xy)}{e^{x-y}}=\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\frac{\frac{y+xy'}{1+x^2y^2}e^{x-y}- \arctan(xy)(1-y')e^{x-y}}{(e^{x-y})^2} = 0\\
\frac{\frac{1+y'}{2}e^{0}- \arctan(1)(1-y')e^{0}}{(e^{o})^2} = 0\\
(1+y')- 2\arctan(1)(1-y') = 0\\
y'=\frac{2\arctan(1)+1}{2\arctan(1)+1} = 1
$$

Which one of these is right?

**Edit:**
I think I see the error in technique 2. However, Maple insists it's $1$.
$$1+y'-\frac{\pi}{2}(1-y')=0\\
2+2y'-\pi+\pi y'=0\\
y'(2+\pi) +2-\pi = 0\\
y'= \frac{\pi-2}{\pi+2}
$$

Comment: The mistake is in "technique 2", at the very last line : one of the two "+" should be a "-".

Comment: It's strange. In Maple, by typing implicitdiff(arctan(xy) = (1/4)*pi*e^(x-y), y, x), I get it to be $1$.

Comment: Maybe you should exchange $x$ with $y$, i.e. write $x,y$ instead of $y,x$?